# Microsoft dynamic CRM Custom activity trouble

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm

im trying to add a costume activity to my CRM server according to this walk-through:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704600.aspx

when i try to publish a work flow with my activity i get an error. the trace flie says :

```
>MSCRM Error Report:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Error Number: 0x80045001

Error Message: Workflow compilation failed:
WF363: Type QAAddActivity, Nothing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d888809fdb5a2449 is not marked as authorized in the application configuration file.

Error Details: Workflow compilation failed:
WF363: Type QAAddActivity, Nothing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d888809fdb5a2449 is not marked as authorized in the application configuration file.

Source File: Not available

Line Number: Not available

Request URL: http://192.168.2.82/Leverate/_grid/cmds/dlg_activate.aspx?iObjType=4703&iTotal=1&iIndex=0&iId={CAF35EFA-80C0-418B-A97B-06820760D777}

Stack Trace Info: [CrmException: Workflow compilation failed:
WF363: Type QAAddActivity, Nothing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d888809fdb5a2449 is not marked as authorized in the application configuration file.]
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.WorkflowServiceInternal`1.CompileWorkflow(ExecutionContext context, WorkflowEntity definition, List`1 dependencies, List`1 customActivityIds, Guid activationId)

[CrmException: Workflow compilation failed:
WF363: Type QAAddActivity, Nothing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d888809fdb5a2449 is not marked as authorized in the application configuration file.]
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.WorkflowServiceInternal`1.CompileWorkflow(ExecutionContext context, WorkflowEntity definition, List`1 dependencies, List`1 customActivityIds, Guid activationId)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.WorkflowServiceInternal`1.CompletePublishing(WorkflowEntity definition, List`1 dependencies, List`1 customActivityIds, ExecutionContext context)
```

though i added this to the web.config :

```
<System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler>
    <authorizedTypes>

      <authorizedType Assembly="Nothing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d888809fdb5a2449" Namespace ="Nothing" TypeName="QAAddActivity" Authorized="True" />
```

help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean 'Custom Workflow Activity' and it looks like your question has been answered over on the Dynamics CRM Microsoft support forums:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/c937c16e-a792-4a33-8d90-004db790a59a